# Не совпадает местоположение элемента в инспекторе и его отображение.в safari

Tags: html, css, safari

столкнулся с дикой проблемой кроссбраузерности. Конкретно в safari многие элементы начинают плыть, наезжать друг на друга и т.д, при том на удивление простые элементы.
Что я обнаружил:

1. Если рассматривать элемент через веб-инспектор, то подчеркивание выдаёт его в другом месте. Например, ожидаемый текст в 3 строки. В safari от отображается в одну строку и вылезает за экран, но через веб инспектор он находится в другом месте и занимает 3 строки.
2. Если съехавший текст выделить, то создается его копия в том месте, в котором нужно. То бишь начинает отображаться 2 одних и тех же элемента.
3. Проблему можно "исправить", если включать-выключать свойства css через веб-инспектор. Например, я выключаю и включаю box-sizing: border-box, и элемент располагается ровно в том месте в котором должен быть.

Код примера приложить не могу, так как тогда придется прикладывать весь сайт. Могу предоставить ссылку на него, если потребуется. Проблема есть только в safari, при том что с десктопа, что с телефона.

Comment: почему же весь сайт можно кинут отдельный div например с его стилями который выглядит по другому в safari